# Сохранить изменения объектов с установленными databindings по клику на кнопку

Tags: c#, база-данных, wpf, access

Привет. Я добавил на форму GridView, вывел туда таблицу. Потом я добавил на форму TextBox'ов соответствующих полям таблицы выводящейся в GridView и кнопку "Сохранить". Ко всем TextBox'ам привязал атрибуты из DataBinding. Я указал у всех TexBox'ов параметр "Режим обновления источника данных" - Never, чтобы я смог обновить источник данных по кнопке. Но как это сделать я не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, не приходилось до этого работать с БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (Control c in editPanel.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Binding b in c.DataBindings)
        {
            b.WriteValue();
        }
    }
}
```